# Why is springBoot {} not found?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a build script that looks something like this:

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.2.RELEASE" apply false
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE" apply false
    id("java")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

allprojects {
   // ...
}

project("core") {
    apply(plugin = "org.springframework.boot")
    apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management") // plugin to manage spring dependencies

    dependencies {
        implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
        testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    }

    springBoot {
        mainClassName = "com.example.App"
    }

}
```

However, when building, gradle complains that

```
springBoot {

^ Unresolved reference: springBoot
```

If I remove the `apply false` on the spring plugins in the `plugins {}` block everything works fine.

What I don't understand is that why `springBoot{}` can't be resolved even if I have called `apply(plugin = )` for spring boot in the "core" subproject? 
My understanding is that in `plugins {}` I imported the plugins into the project but not apply it yet. Later in `core` subproject I apply the plugins and configure spring boot.

Comment: Are you using a kotlin or groovy build?

Comment: @smac89 Kotlin dsl

Comment: Try changing `project("core")` to `project(":core")`

Comment: Hmmm still the same error

Comment: I'd probably say to refresh the project and try again, or upgrade your plugin version to the latest available

Comment: I'm using gradle 6.4 and tried `./gradew clean build` but still the same error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the grade doc https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#type-safe-accessors

The build script can not use type-safe accessors in this case because the apply() call happens in the body of the build script. You have to use other techniques instead, as demonstrated here:

Type-safe accessors are unavailable for model elements contributed by the following:

Plugins applied via the apply(plugin = "id") method

The project build script

Script plugins, via apply(from = "script-plugin.gradle.kts")

Plugins applied via cross-project configuration

You have to use configure option like below,

```
configure<SpringBootExtension> {
      mainClassName = “ com.example.App”
}
```